# How to make Icon appear to the right of Nav Drawer and left of mTitle in Navigation Drawer Activity Template in Android Eclipse?

Tags: android, html, xml, eclipse

Does anyone know where I'd want to place my android:icon="@drawable/icon" code in order to make it show up to the right of Nav Drawer and left of mTitle in Navigation Drawer Activity Template in Android Eclipse? Here is a puush of the Template in Eclipse (http://puu.sh/coq3H/05d54acc2e.png) - the white square is where I want the Icon to be, but apparantly the template doesn't come with that capability built in... I've already tried changing the icon in the Manifest and all that does is change the Launcher Icon when I'm trying to place an Action Bar Icon. If anyone knows what to do or could mess around with the Template it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar(); //
```

or

```
ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar(); // if you are using support library
```

and

```
actionBar.setIcon(yourIcon);
```

try this, it will helped you

Comment: I'm placing the following code everywhere I can think of (OnCreate/RestoreActionBar/On Switch) and nothing is happening:        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);